# Setting a condition to print single output only

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty

I'm currently having a problem with smarty

```
{assign var= comparison value=['BO03ADFA3MWIMY','BO03ADFA3DWIMY','BO031SH25MWGMY','BO031SH26MWFMY','BO031SH27MWEMY','BO031SH28MWDMY','BO031SH29MWCMY','BO031SH30MWBMY','BO031SH31MWAMY','BO031SH32MVZMY',]}
{assign var=is_result value=false}

{if in_array($condition, $comparison)}
   <h3 style="color:#FF0000">RESULT</h3>
   {assign var=is_result value=true}
{/if}
```

Above condition is working perfectly fine for me, however when i put 2 or more match condition, it will provide me two or more result

e.g:

```
$condition1==$comparison1
$condition2==$comparison2
```

"RESULT in the output"

```
RESULT
RESULT
```

My expectation of the condition will provide me a single RESULT only for no matter how many the matches conditions are.
Can anyone help me how to create the condition for that?

Comment: What do you mean "when i put 2 or more match condition"? you mean {if $condition1==$comparison1 || $condition2==$comparison2} ?

Comment: i mean, there is two condition that match with the comparison @Borgtex. i want the output only single RESULT. I've tried use {break}. It break the loop but it destroy my other code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [{elseif}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl):

```
{if $condition}
  {*do something*}
{elseif $condition2}
  {*do something else*}
{/if}
```